# Get multiple checkboxes values in a page to a textbox in a different page

Tags: php, html

I have two PHP pages
 1. `sup_select.php` - which is where a user have to select several suppliers for a one item
 2. `suppliers.php` - which contains all the supplier details. User should be able to select multiple checkboxes and and when user click submit the check boxes values must be passed in to the textbox in the `sup_select.php`.

here is my code.

**sup_select.php**

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$nic = $_SESSION['nic'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add Supplier</title>


<style type="text/css">
.supadd {
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="supadd">
  <table width="1260" border="1">
    <tr align="center">
      <th width="126" scope="col">Request No.</th>
      <th width="130" scope="col">Request Date</th>
      <th width="87" scope="col">Item</th>
      <th width="127" scope="col">Item Category</th>
      <th width="168" scope="col">Requested Quantity</th>
      <th width="132" scope="col">Change Quantity</th>
      <th width="89" scope="col">Deliver Before</th>
      <th width="101" scope="col">Suppliers</th>
      <th width="90" scope="col">Forward</th>
      <th width="146" scope="col">Review Request</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ops_order_request_tbl ORDER BY request_number ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<tr align='center'>";
      echo "<td>".$row['request_number']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['request_date']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['item']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['item_cat']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['requested_quantity']."</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='text'></td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['deliver_before']."</td>";

      echo "<td><form name='' method='get' action=''>
      <input name='".$row['request_number']."' type='text' value='".$checked."'><br><a href='suppliers.php'>Add Suppliers</a></form></td>";
      echo "<td><form name='' method='' action=''><input type='button' value='Forward'></form></td>";
      echo "<td><form name='' method='' action=''><input type='button' value='Review'></form></td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 

  } 

  ?>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**supplier.php**

```
/ Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$nic = $_SESSION['nic'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Suppliers</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php 
echo "<div class='supadd'>";
  echo "<table  border='1'>";
    echo "<tr align='center'>";
      echo "<th width='126' scope='col'>Supplier Name</th>";
      echo "<th width='130' scope='col'>Supplier Address</th>";
      echo "<th width='87' scope='col'>Contact Person</th>";
      echo "<th width='127' scope='col'>Telephone</th>";
      echo "<th width='168' scope='col'>Fax</th>";
      echo "<th width='132' scope='col'>Email</th>";
      echo "<th width='89' scope='col'>&nbsp;</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ops_supplier_tbl ORDER BY name ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<tr align='center'>";
      echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['address']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['contact_person']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['telephone']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['fax']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
      echo "<td><form name='' method='post' action='sup_select.php'><input name='supcheck[]' type='checkbox' value='".$row['name']."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
    }
    if(isset($_POST["supcheck"])) 
      {
          $checked = $_POST["supcheck"];
        } 
        else 
        {
            $checked=array();
        } 
        for ($i="0"; $i<count($checked); $i++) 
        { 
            if(!is_numeric($checked[$i])) 
            {
                $checked[$i]='';
            } 
            if(empty($checked[$i])) 
            {
            unset($checked[$i]);
            }
        }
        $checked=implode('<>',$checked);
echo "<input type='text' name='textfield' id='textfield' value='".$checked."'>"; 
echo "</table>";
    echo "<input align='left' type='submit'></form>";   
    echo "</form>";


 echo "</div>";
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I even tried to do it on the same page but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `supcheck[]` should be inner same `<form>`.

Some changes are needed in `supplier.php`

```
<form action='sup_select.php'>
    <table>
        ...
        <input name='supcheck[]' type='checkbox' value='".$row['name']."'>
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

You can access the POST data in PHP using:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST['supcheck']); ?>
```

If you need a button in specify `<TD>` in `<table>`, you can use **button** with Javascript OnClick function to trigger another outside Forms.

```
...
<td><input type='button' onclick='gotoReview(<? echo $supplier_id; ?>)' value='Review'></td>
...
<script>
    function gotoReview(id){
        location.href = 'supply_review.php?id=' + id;
    }
</script>
```